# How to make the user feel Positive

Tags: user-expectation, naming

We are developing a mobile app. The design needs to share a positive experience to the user. Currently once a user confirms a rider in his vehicle, the `CANCEL` button leaves the user a bit negative. I need the message to read, Confirmed, but also hint that the user can cancel the rider. At the same time I dont want to put a `Cancel` button here.

**CURRENT**

Please note, that the blue gradient button illustrates the next button to logically hit.

[image: caregiri offer ride][image: caregiri ride offer accepted]

**EDIT 1**

This is what it looks like now. But I still don't think it looks WOW, do I need some border or, change of text color for the cancel option ?

[image][image]

Comment: Try "Undo" instead of Cancel

Comment: How about putting an edit button up top and making the cancel button visible on tapping the edit button . You got any issues with that ?

Comment: Would love a illustration. This can get confusing.

Answer (score 2):

You could probably show a text "Your trip is confirmed" in a bold green color with a tick mark icon(optional) and below this display text "To cancel your trip click here" in a smaller font size.
[image]

Comment: did not understand, can u help me with a illustration please.

Answer (score 1):

1) You could, instead of using a cancel button, just use text. This might of course not be suited for a web app because of the small tap area..

Like this:

Your trip is confirmed. Enjoy the ride.
Would you like to [cancel](http://google.be) this trip?

2) Make a 'confirmed' button and pressing that will pop up a window asking if you'd like to cancel.

Answer (score 1):

You could try checkbox. Dismiss. The back button. Or not right now. Maybe another small point of reference on a corner, remind me later.
Edit; "Yes, thanks", "No thank you"
If you need to cancel the ride "let us know" and we'll sort out the rest.

Comment: You should edit your original answer with your additional suggestion in your comment (it's a good suggestion, and makes the answer itself more upvotable).